# how do i print outputs like below for my class Book?

Tags: python

Create a class called Book.

When called, description() should return the description.

Here is an example of how Book should work.

book_one = Book("1984", "George Orwell", 6.99)

print(book_one.description())

should print:

Title: 1984

Author: George Orwell

Price: £6.99

book_one = Book("1984", "George Orwell", 6.99, no_pages=328)

print(book_one.description())

should print:

Title: 1984

Author: George Orwell

Price: £6.99

No. of Pages: 328

book_one = Book("1984", "George Orwell", 6.99, year=1949)

print(book_one.description())

should print:

Title: 1984

Author: George Orwell

Price: £6.99

Year Published: 1949

book_one = Book("1984", "George Orwell", 6.99, no_pages=328, year=1949)

print(book_one.description())
should print:

Title: 1984

Author: George Orwell

Price: £6.99

Year Published: 1949

No. of Pages: 328

```
`class Book:

 def __init__(self, title, author, price,no_pages = None, year = None):

  self.title = title

  self.author = author

  self.price = price

  self.no_pages = no_pages

  self.year = year


 def description(self):

  print(f"Title: {self.title}")

  print(f"Author: {self.author}")

  print(f"Price: £{self.price}")

  print(f"No. of Pages: {self.no_pages}")

  print(f"Year: {self.year}")

  return

if __name__ == "__main__":

 book_one = Book("1984", "George Orwell", 6.99,328,year = 1949)
 book_one.description()`
```

Comment: Not sure I see the problem. Your code should work (ignoring the single quote mark that snuck in before the class declaration). Is it that you want to print just the parameters that are provided? If so test each variable for 'is not None' with an if statement for each print line. I am also assuming that your code is indented properly and was just mis-copied in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def description(self):
  return f"""Title: {self.title}

Author: {self.author}

Price: £{self.price}"""
```

Answer (score 0):

The more Pythonic approach to this is to override the __str__ dunder function. In that way you don't explicitly call a function to get the class contents in the format you need for presentation. The *print()* function will look for an implementation of __str__ in the object that it's processing. If that's absent then it will look for __repr__

Something like this:

```
class Book:
    def __init__(self, title, author, price, no_pages=None, year=None):
        self._title = title
        self._author = author
        self._price = float(price)
        self._no_pages = no_pages
        self._year = year
    def __str__(self):
        parts = [
            f'Title: {self._title}',
            f'Author: {self._author}',
            f'Price: £{self._price:.2f}'
        ]
        if self._year is not None:
            parts.append(f'Year Published: {self._year}')
        if self._no_pages is not None:
            parts.append(f'No. of Pages: {self._no_pages}')
        return '\n'.join(parts)


print(Book("1984", "George Orwell", 6.99), '\n')
print(Book("1984", "George Orwell", 6.99, no_pages=328), '\n')
print(Book("1984", "George Orwell", 6.99, year=1949), '\n')
print(Book("1984", "George Orwell", 6.99, no_pages=328, year=1949))
```

**Output:**

```
Title: 1984
Author: George Orwell
Price: £6.99 

Title: 1984
Author: George Orwell
Price: £6.99
No. of Pages: 328 

Title: 1984
Author: George Orwell
Price: £6.99
Year Published: 1949 

Title: 1984
Author: George Orwell
Price: £6.99
Year Published: 1949
No. of Pages: 328
```